# No C32 compiler option for PIC32MX270F256B

Tags: compilation, ide, microcontroller, mplab, pic32

I am trying to compile a code written for PIC32MX270F256B. For this I want to use C32 compiler in MPLAB X IDE V4.15. I am using C32 compiler successfully in all other projects but weirdly enough there is no option for C32 compiler for my PIC32MX270F256B. I can't figure out the reason behind this. Please suggest me solution for this issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your C32 compiler. The PIC32MX series is supported 1.34 and up. The current version is 2.10 and will support the controller you mentioned.
And of course be sure to select the correct controller family when creating the project.